# how to increase the speed of the spinning wheel while rotating in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

- i have a spin wheel of  10 division.
- the spinning starts from a random position on the button click. i
  dont want to stop the spin wheel at the 10th division.

  ```
  void Start()
  {
  Panel = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Panel1");
  Panel.SetActive (false);

  maxAngle = Random.Range (1440.0f, 3600.0f);
  //print("maxAngle"+maxAngle);
  spinning = false;
  anglePerItem = 360/prize.Count; 
  myStartAngle = (maxAngle % 360)*2;
  //print("myStartAngle"+myStartAngle);
  transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, myStartAngle);

  }



  public void Onclick()
  {

  if ( !spinning) {

      randomTime = Random.Range (20, 25);
      itemNumber = Random.Range (1, prize.Count);
      //float maxAngle = 360 * randomTime + (itemNumber * anglePerItem);
  //  float maxAngle = 360;
      StartCoroutine (SpinTheWheel (1 * randomTime, maxAngle));
  }
  }


  IEnumerator SpinTheWheel (float time, float maxAngle)
  {
  spinning = true;

  SpinsEligibleFrSpinner = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("SpinsEligibleFrSpinner");
  SpinsEligibleFrSpinner = SpinsEligibleFrSpinner - 1;
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("SpinsEligibleFrSpinner",SpinsEligibleFrSpinner);

  float timer = 0.0f;        

  float startAngle  =myStartAngle;


  int animationCurveNumber = 0;

  int i=0;
  while (timer < time) {
      //to calculate rotation

      timer += Time.deltaTime;
      angle = maxAngle * animationCurves [animationCurveNumber].Evaluate (timer / time)  ;
      if(i==0)
      {
          //print ("angle---"+angle);
      }
      i = i + 1;

      transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.0f, angle);



      yield return 0;
  }


  spinning = false;


  }
  ```

how can i do that since am using random i dont get any ideas

- is it possible to add a speed if the spin wheel rotation if it is going to
  end at the 10th division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `Random` to initialize the `initial speed` and `deceleration` of your wheel. Then your `Update()` method just spins the wheel given the changing speed value of the wheel.

```
float _speed; //in m/s
float _deceleration; //in m/s^2
bool _spin; 

void Update()
{
  if (_spin)
    {
      transform.Rotate(_speed * Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
      _speed -= _deceleration * Time.deltaTime;

      //Stop when too slow.
      if (_speed < minSpeed)
      {
        if ( //wheel is at 10th position )
          _speed += minSpeed; //Push it a little more. You can use random here too.
        else
          _spin = false;
      }

    }
}

void OnClick()
{
  if (!_spin)
    {
      _spin = true;
      _speed = Random.Range(speedFloor, speedCeiling);
      _deceleration = Random.Range(decFloor, decCeiling);
    }
}
```

Comment: soo it will never ends at the 10th division? @Lincoln

Comment: Yes, edited. Didnt realise that you did not want it to stop at the 10th division.